Magento 2 : Prevent Child product discounts from applying to bundle products
Is there a way to prevent child product discounts from applying to bundle products? I have a bundle product with its own discount, but both the bundle discount and the child product discount are being applied. I only want the bundle product discount to be applied.

How you set those discount currently?

I'm using Special Price for simple products and I set special price also for bundle product.

Generally in this case, magento always apply special price of products.
But you need to try this solutions.
Step-1: Create an events.xml in the following below path

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
      <observer name="Vendor_Extension_Pricechangetocart" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Priceupdatetocart" />
    </event>
</config>

Step-2: Next Create a Priceupdatetocart.php on following path.

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\Priceupdatetocart.php

<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 
class Priceupdatetocart implements ObserverInterface
{
     
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
   {
            
            $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

            $price = 500; //SET YOUR Price HERE

            $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
            
            $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            
            $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);    
    }
}


I want to prevent Bundled Product Discount to be Applied on Bundled Product Items with already Special Price

Yes, into that observer, you need to set Orignal price of that main bundel product instade of discounted price.

If answer help you, upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community as well.

In Magento 2, there isn't a built-in feature to prevent child product discounts from applying to bundle products. However, you can achieve this by creating a custom module that overrides the default discount calculation behavior.
Here's a high-level overview of what you need to do:

Create a new Magento 2 module.
Override the Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price class.
In your overridden class, modify the getFinalPrice method to only apply the bundle product discount.

Here's a basic example of how you might override the getFinalPrice method:
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;

class Price extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price
{
    public function getFinalPrice($qty, $product)
    {
        // Get the original final price
        $finalPrice = parent::getFinalPrice($qty, $product);

        // Check if the product is a bundle product
        if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            // Get the bundle product discount
            $bundleDiscount = $this->getBundleDiscount($product);

            // Apply only the bundle product discount
            $finalPrice = $finalPrice * (1 - $bundleDiscount / 100);
        }

        return $finalPrice;
    }

    protected function getBundleDiscount($product)
    {
        // Implement your logic to get the bundle product discount
    }
}

Please note that this is a simplified example and might not cover all edge cases. You might need to adjust it to fit your specific needs. Also, remember to replace Vendor and Module with your actual vendor and module names.
This code should be placed in a file at app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Product/Price.php. You'll also need to create a di.xml file in app/code/Vendor/Module/etc to tell Magento to use your overridden class.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price"/>
</config>

Remember to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento cache:clean after adding these files to apply the changes.
